# Should I include edit and delete as use cases?

Tags: use-case, system-analysis

I'm working in system analysis. Should I take all system operations (including basic operations, such as add/delete/edit) as use cases or not?

Should I focus on core system operations, or must I include all possible operations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of adding separate use cases for "add/delete/edit," I usually add one "CRUD" (Create Read Update Delete) use case. This greatly reduces the number of use cases, but still gets your point across. Then again, if it's not a very important part of the system, you might not need to include it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an expert on this topic, but I think that use cases generally focus on core systems operations, and that it is probably not necessary to include all possible operations.